# How do I find the name of the program that would launch a given file?

Tags: java, swing, swt, cross-platform

I am looking for a way to find the name of the program (in my code) that will launch when an operating system tries to open a given file. I will not be launching the application I'm just looking for its name.  Ideally the routine I'm looking for/building would take a filename and return a string.  I am programming in Java 8 on Eclipse and need my jar file to stay cross platform.

Simplest solution I can find is to use SWT's class 'Program'.  Although this assumes that I can correctly identify filetype which is another big can of worms I'm not going to into here.

```
String ext = extractFileType(filename);
Program p2 = Program.findProgram(ext);
if (p2 != null) programName = p2.toString();
```

But for a number of reasons I DON'T WANT TO USE the SWT library if at all possible.  I'm using Swing and and I really don't want my clients to need to download a different application (jar) dependent on their operating system.   I'm well aware that the underlying code is operating system/Window Manager dependent.

1. Anyone know of any other package besides SWT that already does this? I can't find one. Or similar enough I can strip the results to get what I want?  Even if it's only for one platform? I'm experimenting with Apache Tika but I don't see anything helpful there.
2. Any hints on where to look to start write this myself? I know this entails reading the registry on Windows.  I need this code to work on the most recent versions of Windows, and OS X. And eventually Linux but Linux windowing systems are not a priority.
3. Is there a way to link/load SWT in Eclipse to make the cross-dependent part of using SWT this code a little more lightweight and invisible to the end user? I'm not new to coding but am to using Eclipse.

Comment: Swing doesn't execute without AWT classes. Swing is built on top of AWT, so if you use Swing you are also using AWT. Although "Program" is not part of the JDK so I'm not sure what that class is.

Comment: This doesn't exist within the core libraries (in anyway which accissible to us anyway), you will need to investigate using a JNI/JNA solution

Comment: AWT, like Swing, is part of the core API, so if you have Java installed, you have AWT and Swing installed (and now JavaFX)

Comment: The `Program` class seems to belong to SWT, not AWT.

Comment: It's platform dependent.   @MadProgrammer has the best advice IMO - JNI.  It'll be pretty straightforward to implement and you can learn something if you've never done it before. See [The Java Native Interface](https://www.fer.unizg.hr/_download/repository/jni.pdf).

Comment: Opps. I should have said SWT not AWT.  Program isn't part of Swing and doesn't work unless you add SWT Library.

Comment: I'll look into The Java Native Interface. Thanks

Comment: *"I am looking for a way to find the name of the program (in my code) that will launch when an operating system tries to open a given file. "*  .. Why?

Comment: Why not `java.awt.Desktop`?

Comment: You can just look at `Program`'s implementation, it's open-source.

Comment: java.awt.Desktop doesn't give you this functionality.

Comment: JNI looked promising as the native code on both Windows & Mac are fairly simple.  But compiling on my Mac has been difficult as it seems JNI isn't supported by Apple very well anymore.

Comment: After going around in circles I've ended up implementing this with Java Native Access (JNA).  And to call the Objective C function `NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace` I ended up writing my own dynamic library.  Works well in my test code.  Thanks.  This did help put me on the right track.

Comment: @backtocoding Would you mind sharing your solution here? I'm sure there will be others with the same requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick description of my solution.  I did a fair amount of hunting around and I deciding on simply using the JNA library. https://github.com/java-native-access/jna  and writing my own native library on a Macintosh to get it to work.

Windows:  Fairly straight forward usage of JNA.  I'm calling FindExecutable & PathFindExtension from JNA.

```
public interface MyShell32 extends Shell32 {
    MyShell32 INSTANCE = (MyShell32) Native.loadLibrary("shell32",  MyShell32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    WinDef.HINSTANCE FindExecutable(String  lpFile, String lpDirectory, char[] lpResult);
}

{
 ...
    char[] returnBuffer = new char[WinDef.MAX_PATH];
    shell.FindExecutable(filename, null, returnBuffer);
    app = Native.toString(returnBuffer);
   ...
}
```

PathFindExtention() call is similar but returns a pointer so it's more straight forward.

Macintosh:  I tried all sorts of things and finally decided to write my own tiny native library to call in objective C

```
rtnValue = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] getInfoForFile:filenameNS
                                             application:&AStr
                                                    type:&TStr];
```

This library is tiny (but I may add to it if I need other native calls) but I need to write a C/C++ shell as well as the Objective C to get it to work. I then call this library JNA.  Not that different from writing straight JNI but I found it easier to code.

```
public interface NSWWraper extends Library  {
    /** The instance **/
    NSWWraper INSTANCE = (NSWWraper) Native.loadLibrary("NSWWraper", NSWWraper.class);

    // CP_NSWWraper
    Pointer FindFileInfo(String filename);
    void FreeMem(Pointer memory);
}
```

I honestly haven't tested this calling this a large number of files so I don't know how much it slows down my code. JNA calls are supposed to be expensive.  It's interesting timing on someone asking for my solution as I'd had to put this on back burner and only got it working on Windows yesterday.  I was going to incorporate this into the rest of my project today.

Edited to add. I didn't use JINI because I found it's not being very well supported on a Macintosh anymore and JNA was the better solution for Windows and I had to use it anyway.